# How to place and receive phone calls on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, mobile-broadband, telephony, wwan

I have a 4G modem with a valid SIM card on a Debian PC.

The WWAN card is a Fibocom L850GL provided by Lenovo on a new X1C7.

I have `modem-manager-gui` and I can send and receive SMS with it.

How can I make place and receive a voice phone call:

- from the command line
- Using a GUI

Comment: Hopefully 4G modems are exposed as a /dev/tty - and this may be a good starting point - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439119/how-to-get-audio-in-and-out-of-huawei-gsm-modems-when-doing-a-voice-call

Comment: I want to receive call with the SIM number, can I access the GSM network using my WWAN card?

Answer (score -1):

First, check with your WWAN ISP  and ask if they support voice calls over their network and have an app for that. If not, you need a Voice Over IP client app (AKA 'softphone') for Debian, such as one of these listed at https://www.linuxlinks.com/voip/ and https://www.ubuntupit.com/top-20-best-linux-voip-and-video-chat-software/ (there are many more).

I've used T-Mobile, ATT, and Sprint voice clients from Windows laptops with WWAN cards, but none of them supported Debian.

You may also need an account with a telephone provider; maybe your ISP provides this, maybe they don't.  Depending on where you are, [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com/) may be free (US & Canada, IIRC) if you have a Gmail or other Google account, and works well if you launch it from within Chromium or Chrome.

Skype allows outbound calls for free the last time I looked, but getting a PSTN ('Public Switched Telephone Network') number was not free, so you would be limited to other Skype users unless you paid.

The last time I had a paid account for PSTN access not with Google or Skype, I paid by the minute plus per call connection plus a flat monthly fee, but it wwas very reasonable.

Your WWAN provider also may block softphone calls; it's up to their Terms and Conditions.

Comment: Thanks but do you realize I asked to use my own SIM card within the WWAN device? Something such as www.onesimcard.com is what I have, voip is different need, it rely on the network you are already subscribing an IP on. This means you are connected to wifi or cellular network. I must use the cellular network and I am not interested of doing an HoTspot with my phone.

Comment: Didn't think you wanted to hotspot. Everything above is specific to cellular data connections from a laptop to a cellular ISP.

Comment: VOIP implies you are having an IP, where do you get your IP from? If it's from 4G network, then perhaps I can use VOIP but that's not a GSM call. Isn't it possible to make GSM call like on an old Nokia 3310?

Comment: Depends on whether your carrier supports GSM and if they have a GSM softphone client app. _First, check with your WWAN ISP and ask if they support voice calls over their network and have an app for that._

Comment: This is completely not answering the question. I understand I can use VOIP to make call, but how can I receive phone call on +3324298420 (my number) using a Fibocom L850GL wwan card ?

Comment: Having spent quite a bit of time trying to find what you want has been fruitless. Bless your heart.

Comment: I know. Sorry for that. I've spent even more time and so far I didnt find how to send Sms from commande line and how to make call. You were not answering the question at all as you offered to use skype and over voip tools, you didnt help to send sms as you offered to send email or use an external api.  Nothing that I could not do without my 4g modem. Bless you too